# Unicode character not showing properly

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, codepages

I am working on a classic asp application hosted in IIS 6. In one asp page user enters some data and this data is e-mailed using Jmail utility.

When the user enters Swedish characters like äöü the mail does not display these characters properly. I found that setting charset in the  tag will help. But it is causing me more confusions. The website is hosted on two machines and application is behaving quite differently in both the machines.

**Machine 1**:

If I set Charset to UTF-8 unicode characters are displayed as two characters. Browser is sending data in UTF encoding but server is decoding in ASCII.

If I set the charset to ISO-8859-1 unicode characters are displayed properly.

**Machine 2**:

If I set Charset to UTF-8 unicode characters are displayed properly.

If I set Charset to ISO-8859-1 unicode characters are not displayed at all.

**Question:**
How can I make the same code work in both places?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the encoding in the 2 machine to UTF-8.

[how to set encoding in iis.](http://blog.lowtek.com/2006/09/setting-utf-8-character-encoding-for.html)

copy all the files from the machine 2(That work only with UTF-8) to machine 1.

and then try.

Comment: The link explains a way to include charset value in http header. That is same as setting <META> tag.